# max size for a Tcl value (2147483647 bytes) exceeded

Tags: tcl, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to execute a TCL script through Ubuntu console,

Example test script exeuction in Console

```
tcl Main.tcl -file xxxx -test xxxx | tee test.log
```

It was throwing an error message without executing my script **max size for a Tcl value (2147483647 bytes) exceeded**

**My Machine TCL Version**

```
% puts $tcl_version
8.6
```

**My Machine TCL Platform**

```
%   parray tcl_platform
tcl_platform(byteOrder)     = littleEndian
tcl_platform(machine)       = x86_64
tcl_platform(os)            = Linux
tcl_platform(osVersion)     = 3.13.0-32-generic
tcl_platform(pathSeparator) = :
tcl_platform(platform)      = unix
tcl_platform(pointerSize)   = 8
tcl_platform(threaded)      = 1
tcl_platform(user)          = vkosuri
tcl_platform(wordSize)      = 8
```

But it was running fine with other Ubuntu machine without giving any error message

**Other Machine TCL Version**

```
% puts $tcl_version
8.4
```

**Other Machine TCL Platform**

```
% parray tcl_platform
tcl_platform(byteOrder) = littleEndian
tcl_platform(machine)   = x86_64
tcl_platform(os)        = Linux
tcl_platform(osVersion) = 2.6.28-19-generic
tcl_platform(platform)  = unix
tcl_platform(threaded)  = 1
tcl_platform(user)      = vkosuri
tcl_platform(wordSize)  = 8
```

Could someone explain what went wrong with my machine.

Thanks

Malli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was freeTDS package on Ubuntu http://www.freetds.org/

### 1st Approach

The queries are working well with freeTDS == 0.63, but my Ubuntu has freeTDS 0.93, now i downgraded freeTDS 0.93 to 0.63, it is working fine.

**freeTds 0.63 source**

ftp://ftp.freetds.org/pub/freetds/old/0.63/freetds-0.63.tar.gz

**Setting up SQL Server connection on my Ubuntu Box**

Required libraries/programs

> ```
> tclodbc >= v2.5.1 
>
> unixODBC >= v2.2.11 
>
> freeTDS == 0.63
> ```

**Configuration**

Edit /etc/odbcinst.ini and include the following section:

> Description        = SQL Server 2005
>
> Driver Driver             = /usr/lib/odbc/libtdsodbc.so

### **2nd Approach**

Copy libtdsodbc.so to /usr/lib/odbc/

I have placed libtdsodbc.so in my Google drive, you can download

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_cUPwVRE2oUXzIzX0NNSG1VZ1E&authuser=0

Hope it will work.

Thanks

Malli

Answer (score 3):

That looks exactly like you might be hitting a limit on the size of memory block that can be allocated in one piece. The 2GB limit on 64-bit platforms is a [long-standing bug](http://core.tcl.tk/tcl/tktview?name=219196) (assigned to me!) that can't be fixed without utterly destroying the ABI, which is why it's not been fixed yet. When you hit the limit, Tcl fails. It doesn't always fail catastrophically — that depends partially on what sort of context it has for recovery at the C level at the point when the problem is hit — but it most certainly can just keel over.

Since this is a known issue, your best bet would be if you can find a workaround. Can you process your data a bit at a time instead of in one massive chunk? (We'd need to see more of your code to make specific suggestions, of course.)

Comment: I am getting a huge amount of data from database a basic example would be **set dbHandle [connectDB]; set hugeData [getAllProductInfoFromDB];** It was failing at getAllProductInfoFromDB procedure because it was returing huge amount strings from database. _could you please explain how to split data_

Comment: Adjust the SQL with a LIMIT and OFFSET.  Cycle through the records a chunk at time.

Comment: @Malli If a particular record is the culprit you could truncate the string. substring(column for nnn).

Comment: I know this bug hasn't been fixed in 6 years but I just ran into it.  Can you fix it right now?  k thx.